# How to create own theme with own content in PrestaShop 1.6

Tags: javascript, php, css, prestashop

I have my page in html, css and javascript. My goal is to create website(e-shop) which looks like one, that I have. I tried to create new theme, edit it, but I can't understand how PrestaShop works. So main problems:

1. How I can change whole content of the PrestaShop. I found, that it is possible in template files, but can't understand from where system takes it (because I saw variables in tpl).
2. How I can add my css files? I saw, that there is file like global.css (in default theme), it sets style in whole page, but problem is that I need to add my own css files.
3. Same is about javascript. How I can import js files?

To sum up, I need to understand how PrestaShop system with theme works and how I can create my page from templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should dig around on their website and the official designers guide. 

 [Link Here](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Designer+Guide) 

I haven't gone thru it, but looks quite comprehensive.

And as of StackOverFlow, please try some solutions out with the help of the Guide and come back with what you have tried and what is not working for you. Community will be more than happy to offer help on specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Prestashops default theme is built using bootstrap. You can edit those bootstrap files to modify the theme. It is recommended to copy the default theme and edit it instead of creating a new one from scratch.

Each module has its own css file. you need to edit them to modify the modules style.